# solving a trig equation numerically with in-browser JS

Tags: javascript, math, numeric, numerical-methods, numerical

Given values for the variables `s`, `v`, and `h`, and given a library such as [numeric.js](http://www.numericjs.com/index.php) how can I numerically solve [the following equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary#Determining_parameters) for `a` within a given degree of accuracy?

[image: singular transcendental trig equation]

I'm wanting a JS algorithm for use in-browser.

Comment: You should do the algebraic transformations to turn it into `a = XXX`, where `XXX` is an equation in terms of `s`, `v`, and `h`. Then it should be straightforward to calculate it using the functions in `numeric.js`. If you need help with the math, math.stackexchange.com is the place for that.

Comment: @Barmar I have no clue how to separate `a` onto its own side of the equation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Web_Designer Well that a rudimentary algebra referesher seems to to be needed.

Comment: math.stackexchange.com is your first stop.

Comment: I've taken algebra and a little calc, it's just that the `a` variable that needs to be isolated appears in the denominator of the value in the hyperbolic cosine function. I don't know how to get it out.

Comment: Know of any trig identities that would help?

Comment: @Barmar: The referenced Wikipedia article states that “This is a transcendental equation in a and must be solved numerically.” So solving for *a* algebraically very likely won't work unless Wikipedia is wrong. Which turns this into a question more about numerics, and how to implement them in JS, which imho makes this a valid post for SO. Please consider this before (or instead of) voting to close.

Comment: Once the project for which you need this has been completed and is available online, will you provide a link to it? This looks interesting.

Comment: I am voting to close this question.  As the answers make abundantly clear the core of the question is not programming, it is maths.

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1000447/35416

Answer (score 5):

## Separating variables and parameters

You could start by substituting b = a/h. That would turn your equation into

> 2b*sinh(1/(2b)) = sqrt(s²-v²)/h

That way you have all the inputs on the right hand side, and the variable on the left hand side, but unfortunately still occuring in several places in a transcendental form. The benefit is that we can now treat the right-hand side as a single number in order to gain some understanding of this function.

## First look at a plot

The function seems reasonably well-behaved:

[image: Plot of the function]

So you can do [standard numerical root-finding methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm), e.g. [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), to find the position where this function takes a given value (i.e. the one you computed from the right-hand side). If you interpret root-finding as finding locations where a function is zero, then the function for which you want to find zeros is the difference, i.e.

> 2a*sinh(h/(2a)) - sqrt(s²-v²)

## Using optimization from numeric.js

If you want to make use of [numeric.js](http://www.numericjs.com/index.php), `numeric.uncmin` would likely be your best bet. At least it's the best I could find in the docs so far. (Perhaps there is some bare root-finding implementation in there, but if so, I couldn't find it yet.) You'd try to find the minimum of the function

> (2a*sinh(h/(2a)) - sqrt(s²-v²))²

interpreted as a function of a, and hope that that minimum is actually (close to) zero. You might get better results (i.e. faster convergence and/or lower error) by also providing the gradient (derivative) of that function as a separate argument. You can [use Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%28%282a*sinh%28h%2F%282a%29%29-sqrt%28s%5E2-v%5E2%29%29%5E2%29%2Fda) to find that derivative.

## Further rewriting of the function

Let's define f as f(b) = 2b*sinh(1/(2b)). You are trying to find out at what position f assumes a given value. In order to make convergence faster, you can try to turn this f into a different function which will be close to linear. Toying around with plots, I've come up with this:

> g(b) = (f(b) - 1)^(-1/2)

You can apply the same conversion to the right hand side to see the desired value for this function. For b > 0.06 this looks fairly linear, so it should converge really fast. Provided your parameters are expected to be in that range where it is almost linear, but even for smaller *b* it should be no worse than the original formulation. You could use the linear form to compute the starting position of your Newton's method, but I wouldn't bother: as long as you start with a reasonably big value, the first step of Newton's method will do just that.

[image: Plot of g]

Answer (score 2):

1. **this is transcendent equation**

   I assume **real domain** in that case you can not separate the unknown from it (in general) instead you still can solve it numerically (as you intended)
2. **I am too lazy to do proper analysis of `2a.sinh(h/2a)=sqrt(s.s-v.v)`**

   but if I see it right  then `2a.sinh(h/2a)` is monotone so let `c=sqrt(s.s-v.v)` for simplicity and speed up. As I see it `c >= 0` so if `h >= 0` then `a = <0,+inf)`
3. **find value crossing**

   ```
   double a0,a1,da=initial accuracy step;
   for (a1=0.0;2a.sinh(h/2a)<=sqrt(s.s-v.v);a1+=da);
   ```

   now `a1` holds approximate top bound solution

   ```
   for (a0=a1;2a.sinh(h/2a)>sqrt(s.s-v.v);a0-=da);
   ```

   now `a0` holds approximate low bound solution
4. **find solution in desired accuracy**

   if `a0==a1` then you have found exact solution so stop

    if `fabs(a1-a0)<=accuracy` you are inside your accuracy so stop and lower the `da` for example `da*=0.01;` this will boost accuracy `100` times. Now search for solution again but only on interval `<a0,a1>` and repeat this until solution is found

**[notes]**

Another example of solution of transcendent equation is here: [solving Kepler`s equation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25403425/2521214). When nothing else works you still can try this:

- [How approximation search works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36368290/2521214)