# Javascript - Get minimum integer solution of computer equation

Tags: javascript, math

I am having a problem trying to solve an equation in programming.

Imagine I have this line of code:

```
Math.round(((x / 5) + Math.pow(x / 25, 1.3)) / 10) * 10;
```

Given x = 1000, the result is 320.

Now, how can I solve this equation given a result?

Imagine given the result 320 I want to get the **minimum** integer value of x that resolves that line of code.

```
/*320 =*/ Math.round(((x / 5) + Math.pow(x / 25, 1.3)) / 10) * 10;
```

I am having some hard time because of the Math.Round. Even thought that expression is a linear equation, the Math.Round makes way more solutions than one for x, so I want the **minimum** integer  value for my solution.

**Note that x is a integer and if I set x = 999 the result is still 320.**

If I keep lowering x I can see that 984 (atleast in Chrome 64.0.3282.186) is the correct answer in this case, because is the lowest value of x equals to 320 in that expression/programming line.

Comment: Parentheses are unbalanced in both of those code snippets.

Comment: You know the fact that sometimes it's really hard to figure out the inputs of some equations based on a given output is the very basis of cryptography

Comment: but `984` is lower than `990` so, how can 990 be the correct answer?

Comment: @JaromandaX I tested this function in C#, completely forgot that different compilers could have different behaviors like interpreting floating points. Can someone tell me if different browsers or computers might have different behaviors like this one?

Comment: "*Even though that expression is a linear equation…*" sure, so you can apply regression to solve it. Once you've worked out the mathematic algorithm, then attempt a solution. Post again if you have trouble with that, not the maths.

Comment: What have you tried?  I see a solicitation to solve the problem and not any code.  Have you attempted a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving the equation with the Math.round just introduces boundary conditions.

If:

```
Math.round(((x / 5) + Math.pow(x / 25, 1.3)) / 10) * 10 = 320
```

Then:

```
Math.round(((x / 5) + Math.pow(x / 25, 1.3)) / 10)  = 32
```

By dividing both sides by 10.  Now you have:

```
Math.round(expression) = 32
```

Which can be expressed as an inequality statement:

```
31.5 < expression < 32.4999..
```

The expression being equal to 31.5 represents one boundary, and the expression being equal to 32.499.. represents the other boundary.So solving for the boundaries would require solving for:

```
expression = 31.5 and expression = 32.49999...
((x / 5) + Math.pow(x / 25, 1.3))/10 = 31.5  and 
((x / 5) + Math.pow(x / 25, 1.3))/10 = 32.4999
```

Solving these two for x will give you the range of valid values for x.  Now that's just algebra which I'm not going to do :)

Comment: Would this work if the result was 32 instead 320? If you divide 32 by 10: `3.2 = Math.round(expression)`. Isn't that impossible since Math.round always round to a integer?

Comment: Yea that's impossible.  Math.round(x) can never equal 3.2 so there would be no solution for x.

Comment: Exprove if you think I answered your question please mark it as correct so I can get some yummy stack overflow points for it :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the most reliable way that works (albeit somewhat naive) is to loop through all valid numbers and check the predicate.

```
function getMinimumIntegerSolution(func, expectedResult){
  for(let i = 0 /*Or Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER for -ves*/; i< Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER ; i++ ) { 
    if(func(i) === expectedResult)
        return i;
  }
}
```

Now

```
getMinimumIntegerSolution((x) => Math.round(((x / 5) + Math.pow(x / 25, 1.3)) / 10) * 10 , 320)
```

This returns what you expect, 984

Comment: I have done this approach before posting this question, but for being honest it seems somewhat a "lazy" method. However is a solution and it is an easy one to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because the function defined by

```
f(n) = Math.round(((x / 5) + Math.pow(x / 25, 1.3)) / 10) * 10
```

is monotonous (in this case, increasing), you can do a binary search.
Note that I wrote the following code originally in Java, and it is syntactically incorrect in Javascript, but should hopefully be straightforward to translate into the latter.

```
var x0 = 0;
var x1 = 1e6;
var Y = 320d;
var epsilon = 10d;

var x = (x1 - x0) / 2d;
var y = 0;

while (Math.abs(Y - (y = f(x))) > epsilon) {
   if (y > Y) {
      x = (x - x0) / 2d;
   } else {
      x = (x1 - x) / 2d;
   }
   // System.out.println(y + " " + x);
}

while (f(x) < Y)
   ++x;

// System.out.println(Math.round(x) + " " + f(x));
```

Running it on my computer leaving the `System.out.println` uncommented:

```
490250.0 250000.0
208490.0 125000.0
89370.0 62500.0
38640.0 31250.0
16870.0 15625.0
7440.0 7812.5
3310.0 3906.25
1490.0 1953.125
680.0 976.5625
984 320.0
```

- Note that the last loop incrementing `x` is guaranteed to complete in less than `epsilon` steps.
- The values of `x0`, `x1` and `epsilon` can be tweaked to provide better bounds for your problem.
- This algorithm will fail if the value of `epsilon` is "too small", because of the rounding happening in `f`.
- The complexity of this solution is `O(log2(x1 - x0))`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @webnetweaver answer. If you rearrange the final equation you get a high-order polynomial (13th degree) which is difficult to solve algebraically. You can use numerical methods as [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). For numerical methods in JavaScript you can use [numeric.js](http://www.numericjs.com). You also need to solve only for the lower bound (31.5) in order to find the lowest integer x because the function is monotonic increasing. See also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753546/solving-a-trig-equation-numerically-with-in-browser-js) on numerical equation solving in JavaScript.

Here is a solution using Newton's method. It uses 0 as initial guess. It only takes five iterations for getting the minimum integer solution.

```js
var result = 320;
var d = result - 5;

function func(x) {
  return x / 5 + 0.0152292 * Math.pow(x, 1.3) - d;
}

function deriv(x) {
  return 0.2 + 0.019798 * Math.pow(x, 0.3);
}

var epsilon = 0.001; //termination condition

function newton(guess) {
  var approx = guess - func(guess) / deriv(guess);
  if (Math.abs(guess - approx) > epsilon) {
    console.log("Guess: " + guess);
    return newton(approx);
  } else {
    //round solution up for minimum integer
    return Math.ceil(approx);
  }
}

console.log("Minimum integer: " + newton(0));
```