# Get random vector3 on plane

Tags: c#, math, vector, unity-game-engine, geometry

There are the planet and a few satellites in 3d space. I need to calculate axis of rotation for every satellite. They should rotate around planet center.

I calculated the vector from satellite to the center of the planet.

```
vec1 = planetCenter - sputnikCenter;
```

With vec1 and planetCenter I can calculate the equation of plane, that perpendicular to vec1.

equation like that:

```
A.x + B.y + C.z + D = 0
```

Now, I should get random vector on this plane. This vector will be axis of rotation. But how can I get this random vector?

Comment: So in general you want to rotate objects at random distance around another object?

Comment: @HamzaHasan There is a method object.Rotate(axis, angle); So, I have to calculate that axis and call this method.

Comment: @HamzaHasan the distance of rotation equal the current distance between planet and sputnik

Comment: So in your case it would be `Vector3.up` so it will rotate in x-z axes. But I think you want rotation like moon around earth. Right?

Comment: Actually your question is not that clear, can you please edit it with some examples?

Comment: @HamzaHasan yep, I want to rotate around center of planet.

Comment: @Yuri if you want to rotate around the planet, the plane you've calculated doesn't really help you. Its normal is a vector in the plane in which you want to rotate. You actually need a vector that is perpendicular to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well if you got the plane `A.x + B.y + C.z + D = 0` then `n(A,B,C)` is the normal vector. So I think the easiest approach to your task is to use **basis vectors**. So you need `2` perpendicular vectors on this plane. For that you can exploit cross product. first some definitions:

**knowns:**

- `p` planet center position (or the center point of your rotations or any point on the plane so in worst case you can try `p=0,0,-D/C` or any other combinationn...)
- `n` normal vector
- `q= (1,0,0) or (0,1,0)`  chose the one that has lesser `|dot(n,q)|`

**operations:**

- `vector = cross(a,b) = a` **x** `b` - **cross** product returns perpendicular vector to `a,b`
- `scalar = dot(a,b) = (a`**.**`b)` - **dot** product returns `0` if `a,b` are perpendicular
- `|a| = abs(a)` - **abs**olute value (both **scalar** and **vector**)
- `scalar = Rand()` - **float** pseudo random value on interval `<0.0,1.0>`

**unknowns:**

- `u,v` - **basis vectors**
- `r` - your **pseudo-random** point

So first get `u,v` by exploiting cross product:

```
u=cross(n,q)
v=cross(n,u)
```

And now the point:

```
r = p + u*(2.0*Rand()-1.0) + v*(2.0*Rand()-1.0)
```

If you want just random vector then ignore the start position `p`

```
r' = u*(2.0*Rand()-1.0) + v*(2.0*Rand()-1.0)
```

That is all ... so you can compute `u,v` once (per normal vector change) and generate the `r` as often as you need. If `u,v` are unit vectors then this will generate points inside `2x2` square ...  if you want more or less just add scales to them ...

see [Is it possible to make realistic n-body solar system simulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28020934/2521214) and generate random orbital parameters for [Kepler's equation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25403425/2521214) instead ...

Answer (score 0):

Now your question is clear. You want to rotate object around another, like Earth and Sun. May be some other solutions may available but I would do it through LookAt and parametric equation of circle.

`x = r * cos(theta) + displacementX`

`z = r * sin(theta) + displacementZ`

where `r` is radius, distance in your case
`displacementX` and `displacementZ` are the distance from origin. If both (`displacementX` and `displacementZ`) is 0 then it will rotate around `origin (0,0)`

In Object(Earth) script, do it as follow

```
public Transform _sun;
float _theta = 0;

void Start ()
{
    StartCoroutine ("ChangeAngle");
}

void Update ()
{
    transform.LookAt (_sun);
    float newX = (5 * Mathf.Cos (_theta)) + _sun.position.x;
    float newZ = (5 * Mathf.Sin (_theta)) + _sun.position.z;

    transform.position = new Vector3 (newX, _sun.position.y, newZ);
}

IEnumerator ChangeAngle ()
{
    while (true) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.01f);
        _theta += 0.1f;
        if (_theta >= 360)
            _theta = 0;
    }
}
```

You can further play with it

Answer (score 0):

It seems your rotation axis might be random vector that is independent from vec1.
You can generate random unit vector with uniform distribution using methods for [Sphere Point Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html).

Marsaglia method (eq. 9-11) is convenient to generate this vector:
Generate x1 and x2 in range -1..1 such as  `p = x1^2 +x2^2 <= 1` (rejecting bad pairs).
Then

```
x = 2 * x1 * Sqrt(1 - p)
y = 2 * x2 * Sqrt(1 - p)
z = 1 - 2 * p
```