# How to solve sine mathematic equation in java?

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

How to solve following mathematic equation in java?

Equation:
`x + sin(x) = constant`, where x is variable. I encountered this equation after 18 years. I forgot this basic concept. Please help me on this basic high school question.

I tried to code above equation `x + sin(x) = constant` as following, however, it is giving wrong answer. Please let me know where i am wrong.

```
    public double balanceLength(double total_weight) {
        // 5.00 assume inical value of x
        return newtonRaphson( 5.00,  total_weight);
    }
    private static double derivFunc(double x)
    {
        return sin(x) + x;
    }
    private static double func(double x, double weight)
    {
        return sin(x) + x - weight;
    }
    static double newtonRaphson(double x, double weight)
    {

        double h = func(x, weight) / derivFunc(x);
        while (abs(h) >= EPSILON)
        {
            h = func(x, weight) / derivFunc(x);
            x = x - h;
        }

        return round(x * 100.0) / 100.0 ;
    }
```

Comment: This is not a `math` forum :(

Comment: Hint: The function `f(x)=x + sin(x)` is increasing because its derivative is positive or zero, therefore if `f(y) - constant > 0` there is no solution for x >y

Comment: You can use Newton's method (As we're on SO). Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: transcendental equations are solvable only numerically or by approximation if no special case or some identity can convert it to polynomial one ...see [How approximation search works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36163846/2521214) however this case is very similar to [Solving Kepler's equation `M=E-e*sin(E)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25403425/2521214) so simple iteration might do ...

Comment: See [this](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/13flow/Sin.java.html) : when `x` is expressed in radians `sin(x)+x` can be approximated  by `2x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7! + ...`

Comment: You got the derivation wrong. should be `1 + cos(x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very basic implementation, only partially tested. It reruns `x` in radians, which satisfies `y=six(x) +x` for a given `y` :

```
//returned value in radians
static double evaluateSinxPlusx(double y){

    double delta = y>0 ?  0.01 : -0.01 ;//change constants
    double epsilon = 0.01;            //to change
    int iterations = 100;             //accuracy

    double x = 0;
    double sum = 1;

    while(Math.abs(y - sum) > epsilon) {
        x+=delta;
        //based Taylor series approximation
        double term = 1.0;
        sum  = x;
        double d = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i< iterations; i++) {
             term = Math.pow(x, i);
             d*=i;
             if (i % 4 == 1) {

                sum += term/d;
            }
             if (i % 4 == 3) {
                sum -= term/d;
            }
         }
    }
    return x;
}

//test it 
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    double y = 0.979;
    //expected x = 0.5 radians
    System.out.println("for x="+ evaluateSinxPlusx(y)+"(radians), sin(x)+x = "+ y);

    y = -0.979;
    //expected x = - 0.5 radians
    System.out.println("for x="+ evaluateSinxPlusx(y)+"(radians), sin(x)+x = "+ y);

    y = 0.33256;
    //expected x = 0.16666 radians
    System.out.println("for x="+ evaluateSinxPlusx(y)+"(radians), sin(x)+x = "+ y);
}
```

This is not a robust implementation and should be used as demo only.