# Calculate x,y coordinate of point on orbit

Tags: java, math, trigonometry, orbit

I want to calculate x,y coordinates of point on orbit.  I have radius (for example 1), coordinates of center of orbit (0,0) and the time it takes to make full circle on orbit (for example 2), starting coordinates of object(-radius,0), and I want to calculate x and y after 1 day, so it should be on radius,0. But how to calculate it without angle?

Comment: circular or elliptical orbit? Your data suggest 2D circular however if you are doing physically correct model check [n-body simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28020934/2521214) and [Solving Kepler's equation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25403425/2521214)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to have to start by translating the the orbit into a rotation rate, which will give you an equation for `θ(t)`, where `t` and `θ(t)` is the angle (normally in radians) in the orbit at time `t`.  The position would then be given by

```
X ← r·cos(θ(t)) + x0
Y ← r·sin(θ(t)) + y0
```

where `r` is the radius of your orbit (which you indicated was `1`) and `(x0, y0)` is the center of the orbit (which you indicated was `(0,0)`).

If you want the point to have a constant rotation rate and arrive at `(r, 0)` after exactly `1` day, then your `θ(t)` would be a function of the form:

```
θ(t) ← 2·n·π·t + θ(0)
```

Where `t` is time in days and `n` is an integer value. `θ(0)` is just the starting angle which in your case will be `π`.  There are an infinite number of other such functions which could permit this to occur if you wanted to use a non-constant rotation rate, but you would need to provide some additional requirements for that.

A more general function will permit you to specify the constant rotation rate `α` and calculate the angle at a time `t`.  This would take on the form

```
θ(α, t) ← 2·α·π·t + θ(0)
```

So in your example of a rotation rate of `2`, `θ(2, t) = 4·π·t`

Coding this in Java is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @sadge_user, You need to be clear on the units.  A rotation rate of '2' means what exactly?  Is that 2 degrees, 2 radians, 2 complete revolutions around the center?  If it's degrees, use θ(t) ← 2·π·t/180 + θ(0); If radians, use θ(t) = 2·t + θ(0).  If it's two rotations, use the first formulation and set n=2 or that last formulation, θ(2, t) = 4·π·t.