# Tracking the latitude and longitude on the Sun

Tags: image, image-processing, latitude-longitude, astronomy, solar

I have a 4096*4096 image of the Sun.I want to track its latitude and longitude using MATLAB. I have tried the below code. Though it works fine on the axes(latitude=0/90 longitude=0/90), it fails at the edges(for example latitude=30 longitude=90)

```
x=round((b*s*cos((l*pi)/180))+xC)
y=round((-l*s)+yC)

where x=horizontal displacement
y=vertical displacement
l=latitude
b=longitude
(xC,yC)=center coordinates of the Sun
s=scaling factor.
```

Thanks in advance
AU

I am plotting all the longitude points for a given latitude. figure 1 is for latitude=0 while figure 2 and 3 are for latitude=45 and -45 respectively.As I increase the latitude the lines become more skew(see figure  4 for latitude = 70).

Please refer the below link for the images: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2X4xzsGcarCbGM5aVM1UXBRX2M?usp=sharing

I also tried plotting the latitudes for a constant longitude and a similar trend(skewness with increasing longitude) was found.

Comment: and "fails" means what? provide your image, your code and decribe what you expect and what you get. what have you done so far to solve it yourself? please read [ask]

Comment: *"Latitude and longitude"*? Or azimuth and elevation?

Comment: Please refer the below link for the plots: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2X4xzsGcarCbGM5aVM1UXBRX2M?usp=sharing

Comment: heliocentric latitude and longitude

Comment: see [calculate the time when the sun is X degrees below/above the Horizon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25722336/2521214)